# Mongoose: TypeError: doc.validate is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

### Scenario

I have a mongoose model schema as in the following:

```
var TerminalBalanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    currentBalances: [{
        terminalID: {
            type: String,
            // required: '{path} is required'
        },
        balance: {
            terminal: {
                type: Number,
                required: '{path} is required'
            },
            calculated: {
                type: Number,
                required: '{path} is required'
            }
        },
        lastInquiryDate: Date
    }]
});
```

where `currentBalances` is an array of objects.

The collection for the mongoose model `TerminalBalance` based on the above schema always contains a ***single object*** where only the items in `currentBalances` array may change.

## Problem

Whenever I perform something to ***replace*** an object within the array `currentBalances` of the document, and eventually save the same document, I get the following error:

> ```
> x:\node\mynps-tcp-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:104
>   doc.validate({ __noPromise: true }, function(err) {
>       ^
>
> TypeError: doc.validate is not a function
>
> at x:\node\mynps-tcp-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:104:11
> at DocumentArray.SchemaType.doValidate (x:\node\mynps-tcp-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:654:22)
> at DocumentArray.doValidate (x:\node\mynps-tcp-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:77:35)
> at x:\node\mynps-tcp-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1171:9
> at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
> at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
> ```

Note that to replace an object, I loop over the `currentBalances` array and if the object is the same as the one I'm looking for, I replace it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < terminalBalance.currentBalances.length; i++) {
     if(terminalBalance.currentBalances[i].terminalID === response.data.terminalID){
         terminalBalance.currentBalances[i] = balance;
         terminalBalance.save(function (err) {
             console.log('err', err); // this `err` is never thrown, that is the above error is thrown before reaching here 
         });
         break;
      } else { ...
```

> **Mongoose version:** 4.4.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my issue by using [MongooseArray.splice](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.splice) (*which is a wrapper for the built-in JS [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)*) on  the array instead of directly assigning an object at an index to the `currentBalances` array.

```
...
if(terminalBalance.currentBalances[i].terminalID === response.data.terminalID){
     terminalBalance.currentBalances[i].splice(i, 1, balance);  //<=== here
     terminalBalance.save(function (err) {
         console.log('err', err);
     });
     break;
...
```

Comment: That actually isn't `Array.prototype.splice()`, but rather [`MongooseArray#splice()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.splice), which adds tracking to the document.  This helps explain why using `splice()` would solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @c1moore, I'll rectify my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not an actual answer to the question but a tip to achieve what you're trying

There's much easier way to update an object in array using `$elemMatch` and `currentBalances.$` as reference to matched element, I hope this is what you are trying to do

```
TerminalBalance.update({
    $and: [
        {_id: balanceID},
        {currentBalances:{
            $elemMatch:{ terminalID: response.data.terminalID }
        }}
    ]
},{
    $set: 'currentBalances.$': balance}
}, 
function(err, count) { ... });
```

I haven't tried this code so expect some typos.